Reversed probability inequality
Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d (sub-Gaussian) r.v, and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_n$ . Typically, probability inequality usually has the form $P(|\frac{1}{n}S_n - \mathbb E[X]| \ge \epsilon) \le 2\exp(-\frac{n\epsilon^2}{2c^2})$, where the $c$ is a positive constant. However, I am interested in are there any existing proof techniques/inequalities in the form $P(|\frac{1}{n}S_n - \mathbb E[X]| \le \epsilon) \le 2\exp(-\frac{n\epsilon^2}{2c^2})$. In other words, the probability of $\frac{1}{n}S_n - E[X]$ less than $\epsilon$ becomes vanishingly small or $S_n$ goes to infinity if $E[X] >0$.
I have looked into Reverse Markov's inequality, which is $P(X\le a) \le \frac{U- \mathbb E[X]}{U - a}$ where U is the maximum value of X. However, I don't think we generally do not know anything about the maximal of X. Any helps are appreciated!

No, such a thing does not exist, since it would contradict the law of large numbers.
